# Is withdrawing from two courses in my PhD bad for my future?

Tags: phd, withdraw

I am a 2nd year PhD student. So far, I've taken 5 courses, 3 of which I got A and the other two I withdrew from. The reason was mainly it was not until the 6th session that I understood those two courses were not particularly relavant and helpful towards my thesis. My question is how bad is my situation regarding gettting a post doc, faculty position, or a position in industry, in the future?

Comment: I'd say the effects will be negligible. There are plenty of valid reasons students might drop a course.

Comment: Nobody care about the courses you take or do not take. They only care about your papers.

Comment: @qsp: For research-oriented faculty jobs, that's true, but some other academic jobs do pay attention to graduate coursework.  For instance, if you have substantial coursework in a secondary field, that can be helpful evidence that you are qualified to teach courses in that field, which can be a plus for some teaching-oriented jobs.  I am also not sure whether what you say applies to industry.

Comment: Do you have at least a temporary advisor?  If not, you can ask your department to assign you one, or you can seek out a professor you feel some affinity with.  It is always good to check one's progress periodically with someone in your department. // When you meet with this person, bring an unofficial transcript, and find a couple of positives to mention, in addition to the information in your question.

Comment: In general, giving out too detailed information about yourself on the internet can be long term damaging for lots of different aspects in your life. We would probably be able to answer without the details which make co workers and others able to figure out who you are.

Comment: @mathreadler Thanks for the advice, I edited my post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For postdoc and position in the industry, it will not cause any problem. 
However, faculty positions depend on grants, and commitees pick people who are able to obtain fund grants, and publish papers. It is unlikely they will care about your grades.

Comment: why do you think committees are responsible for hiring @padawan?

Comment: Committee, in this context, is used in a generic way. Even if it is one person, there is a process that approves the applications and decides who to accept. This process is held by a **committee**.